# Geany editor background colour

Tags: geany

Padre supports theme. How to change geany editors background colour. How to set up preferences or add themes to geany.

Answer (score 4):

Geany themes (called, color schemes) are located in `~/.config/geany/colorschemes`

You can add more schemes from [this site](https://github.com/geany/geany-themes/).  You'll want to copy from the `colorschemes` folder.

After all the .conf files are added, you can now choose a new color scheme from the menubar.  Choose one that you like, and then edit its .conf file.  In this file, under the section `[named colors]` or `[named styles]`, you can change the background color to whatever you want.  The colors are in RGB hex format.

Comment: nice one, thx dud

Answer (score 4):

If someone just wants to change the background color of Geany editor from white to black, you have to go to Edit -> Preferences -> Editor -> Display and check "Invert syntax highlighting colors".

Comment: **That is the one I was looking for.**  
This way when I edit as root the backgroud is black and when I edit as normal user the background is white.